# should I lock before dlopen?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I do have an *.so library, which obtains some information from system libraries using dlopen. Library can be used by multiple application simultaneously. 
Maybe it is a silly question, but should I flock library before doing dlopen on it? I haven't found direct answer anywhere.

Comment: No. Every program uses its own memory stack when it loads the library. Locking is only for *shared resources*, which is not existant if multiple programs using the same shared library.

Comment: You don't need to flock a file if no one is modifying it.

Comment: I'm more worried about simultaneous access to file (library) on file system.

Comment: The shared library itself? Unless it's being MODIFIED by another process [and it shouldn't, compilers/linkers/file-copying etc, create a complete new file (and in Linux, the old file is "there" until it gets closed by the last user) - so only some process that is opening the library and writing to it could cause this].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what was said in the comments, you don't need a semaphore(flock) unless you are accessing a shared resource that could change on you. (IE. accessing shared memory and needing to ensure concurrency of that data). The way dynamic loading ... dlopen()... works

> [Those two routines are actually simple wrappers that call back into
> the dynamic linker. When the dynamic linker loads a library via
> dlopen(), it does the same relocation and symbol resolution it does on
> any other library, so the dynamically loaded program can without any
> special arrangements call back to routines already loaded](https://web.archive.org/web/20190113062843/https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker10.html)

Because of the way linking works, relocations and modifications to the GOT/PLT are done in the memory space of the ( processes calling dlopen ) not that where the shared object is mapped.

> [If a hundred processes use a shared library, it makes no sense to have
> 100 copies of the code in memory taking up space. If the code is
> completely read-only, and hence never, ever, modified](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html)

Having the shared objects being in read-only memory you never need to worry about them suddenly changing on you sooo no need for a flock :)!

Note: Because you have a shared object linking to other shared objects... the GOT of the initial shared object needs to be updated/mod with the relocations of the libraries being loaded with dlopen() ... but that is stored in a r/w segment of process unique memory space not in that of the shared objects.

> [the shared library must still have a unqiue data instance in each
> process...the read-write data section is always put at a known offset
> from the code section of the library. This way, via the magic of
> virtual-memory, every process sees its own data section but can share
> the unmodified code](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html)